# Display letters in all capitals in a block

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a div with class "title". How do I display all letters in capitals in this block?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_touppercase.asp This might help

Answer (score 9):

CSS can do that

```
.title {text-transform : uppercase;}
```

or jQuery

```
$('.title').text(function(_, txt) {
    return txt.toUpperCase();
});
```

or plain Javascript

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.title');

for (var i=elems.length; i--;) {
    elems[i].textContent = elems[i].textContent.toUpperCase();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
div.title {text-transform:uppercase;}
```